# How to return values from previous day or month?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data for the month of feb and I want to return values of only those days for which data has been recorded.

Ex:

```
Defect           02/01   02/02   02/03    02/04
Missing clip               
Wrong cable       3                5
Wrong BSN                  5       9       6
Damaged harness   4        2       1
```

I want the formula to return the values and defect type for the date of 02/02
I want the formula to return only Wrong BSN and Damaged harness and the corresponding values for that.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Kavya

Comment: You have `02/03` twice, is that a typo or may you have multiple columns of the same date?

Comment: @BruceWayne... its a typo .. it is 02/04

Comment: Are you looking to return the number of times e.g. "Missing clip" was recorded on 02/01?  If so you will need to use a countifs function.  Also does your source table store 02/01 or does it have the full date?  It would be helpful if you post at least the structure of your source data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`=HLOOKUP()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f) to horizontally search for a specific term, and when the formula find the term, it'll return the occurrence in the nth row.

`=HLOOKUP(what_ur_searching, where_ur_searching, which_row_should_return, exact_or_aprox_match)`

It's important to say that `HLOOKUP` will match the first occurrence from left to right. In your example you have `02/03` two times, so if you try to return the `02/03` values, it'll return `9` and `1`, instead of `6` and `null`.

**Wrong BSN:**

Write the following formula in any cell that you want, inside the same worksheet: `=HLOOKUP("02/02",$A$1:$E$5,4;0)`

*Explaining:*

Search in the first row of $A$1:$E$5, the occurrence of the term "02/02". If the formula find it, return the occurrence on the 4th line (where 1 is equal to the header and 4 is equal to the row number of "Wrong BSN" data). The 0 means that it's looking for the EXACT occurence of "02/02".

**Damaged harness:**

Write the following formula in any cell that you want, inside the same worksheet: `=HLOOKUP("02/02",$A$1:$E$5,5;0)`

*Explaining:*

Search in the first row of $A$1:$E$5, the occurrence of the term "02/02". If the formula find it, return the occurrence on the 5th line (where 1 is equal to the header and 5 is equal to the row number of "Damaged harness" data). The 0 means that it's looking for the EXACT occurence of "02/02".

Comment: Thanks a lot @dot.Py.

Comment: How about I don't specify which defect it should return. 
Ex: I want the formula to return all the defects and its value for the date 02/02.

Comment: You can't return many values using only one `=HLOOKUP()` function... you should use 1 function per value that you want to fetch. I.e.: `=HLOOKUP("02/02",$A$1:$E$5,2;0)`, `=HLOOKUP("02/02",$A$1:$E$5,3;0)`, `=HLOOKUP("02/02",$A$1:$E$5,4;0)`, `=HLOOKUP("02/02",$A$1:$E$5,5;0)`